# autocomplete scroll in rtl direction

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

When the overflow-y is added to my .ui-autocomplete list every thing looks fine in the left-to-right look. If I switch to a view with content have dir=rtl.
The scroll bar is place right but the dropdown list seems to reserve the place for the scroll bar at the right side while the scroll itself is on the left.

Check the images attached, to understand my question more.

[image]

Comment: adding padding or margins to be aware of?

Comment: Upload your code on online js feeds, like https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
ul{
direction: ltr;
}

ul li{
text-align: right;
}
```